# How to deal with "queue has been destroyed" error when exporting data from Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, export, apache-iotdb, iotdb

This error: `Cannot dump result because: 301: queue has been destroyed` was reported after exporting part of my time-series data in Apache IoTDB. I tried and found out that this error was reported after exporting data for more than 5 hours (about 1,490,000 time-series). Does anyone know why this error popped out?

Answer (score 0):

This should be similar to a `query timeout` error, and the log of Apache IoTDB should recorded detailed error reasons. To solve this problem, you can try to set the timeout time for `session` query by adding `-t <timeout>` to query statement (unit is ms). The default value for this parameter is 60S.